# Bad kerning in \emph{Kerning}. How to improve?

Tags: pdftex, kerning

When writing about Kerning, the word "Kerning" itself is a bad example, esp. when emphasised. Is there a way to improve the kerning between "K" and "e" once for all in a document?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\emph{Kerning} should work out better.
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is chosen by the font designer so you would need a differnt font, or make a virtual font (which could be done from the document in luatex)

Comment: Sounds difficult.

Comment: Using another font does not need to be difficult. Use, e.g., `\usepackage{XCharter}` and the kerning of *Kerning* would be much better.

Comment: `\usepackage{lmodern}` is not hard

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Or using `lualatex`, right?

Comment: yes the Lua access to fonts is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is chosen by the font designer so you would need a different font, or make a virtual font (which could be done from the document in luatex)

`lmodern` is a very close variant of computer modern:

cmr:

[image]

lmr (`\usepackage{lmodern}`):

[image]

Comment: Computer Modern doesn't apply kerning between upper- and lowercase letters in the latin alphabet.  I believe the original (non)decision was based on limited resources, i.e., very limited memory at the time of development.